# Fit the process in the container Form

Tags: c#, process

I want to start a process in my C# application and I am able to do so by using this code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "chrome.exe";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application";
Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

But when I open this it opens on whole screen, means it covers the whole screen. I need that to be contained within the boundary of my form. Lets say size of form is `906, 495` then this application should open within this area.

I am unable to find that that how can I do this. Secondly I need to set the size of any application. Like I have used Chrome but it may be any other process. Is it possible?

Comment: See if this CodeProject article helps http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "chrome.exe";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application";

//Force chrome to run in a new process
startInfo.Arguments = @"--user-data-dir=C:\sometempdir";

Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);

process.WaitForInputIdle();

//Need to do a little more work make sure we get the Window handle properly
do
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    process.Refresh();
}
while (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero && !process.HasExited);  

//Set these appropriately
int xPos = 0;
int yPos = 0;

MoveWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, xPos, yPos, 906, 495, true);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But this is also not working. If i open chrome it covers whole screen. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Try waiting for the process to open before setting the position like in Rodrigo's answer

Comment: i tried that solution but window covers the whole screen as earlier and after some seconds it throws exception "Process has exited, so the requested information is not available."

Comment: I found the problem. Its because you probably already have a chrome window open and when you run chrome.exe it really just opens a new window in the existing chrome.exe application, which is why that exception is thrown. Try running without already having chrome running and it should work. Not sure how to work around it if chrome is already running though.

Comment: @RafayZiaMir I found a solution. See my updated answer. The trick is to use a command line argument to force chrome to run in a new process, and then we need to do a little more work to wait until we can actually get the WindowHandle

Answer (score 0):

Just as mclaassen suggested, you should use the `MoveWindow` API, however you might want to wait until the window shows up:

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
        Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        process.WaitForInputIdle(); // Wait for interface to load

        MoveWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 100, 100, true);
```